# How can I read a local file with a fixed path in Javascript? I only have the location of the file as a string. NO HTML forms allowed

Tags: javascript

I am creating a web app where I already know the location of a file that needs to be uploaded. Note that all I have is the path (example: Users/username/Downloads or Users/username/Documents) or something like that. How can I get Javascript to read that file as a File object or as a binary string so that I can POST it to a server.

Additionally, this file is not a simple file like a JSON or a txt file. This file would usually be a Microsoft Word file.

Comment: From the browser? No you cannot do that, it would be a security nightmare.

Comment: You can't. If that is possible, then your device is not safe from this person who can use that method to steal your data.

Comment: its dangerous if the broser actually sharing the real path

Comment: please tell us more about your webapp, are you using any backend programming language? (php? etc)

Comment: You can't. Sites can't access the filesystem, even with forms. Real paths are NEVER shared, unless by the user. This is not possible.

Answer (score 3):

Due to security reasons, JavaScript executed from web apps have very limited access to the file system.

The best you can do is have the user select a file via a [file input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file).

If having the web app user install a browser extension is acceptable, a browser extension *may* have more access to the user's file system. Here is an example extension that accesses a user's file system more directly: https://github.com/buggyj/savetiddlers

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't to read the any files from the front-end by javascript, It is not allowed to do so. But you can get the file path from front-end and then pass it to the app framwork or back-end to processing. Beacuse the app's framework or back-end has the ability to access system files. Whereafter, you can POST to the contents of the file to the web server.